# Displaying Only Certain Columns/Properties with Keen DataViz

Tags: keen-io

I'm wondering how to display only certain columns on my table when I'm trying to do data visualization.  Right now, every time that I do a table, it shows every single property or column.  I tried to figure out how to only show certain columns properties by guessing based on the documentation for extraction within the keen.io docs (I've commented out my wrong guess)

```
  var foo = new Keen.Query("extraction", {
   eventCollection: "Purchases",
   targetProperty: "zip",
// I've commented out line 7 because it doesn't work, it was just my guess on syntax...
// how do I only show certain columns of the table (columns are properties)
// vs. showing the entire table?
//   propertyNames: ["zip","businessname"]

   filters: [
   {
     "property_name" : "zip",
     "operator" : "eq",
     "property_value" : "80016"
   },
   {
     "property_name" : "city",
     "operator" : "eq",
     "property_value" : "Aurora"
   }]
 });
 client.draw(foo, document.getElementById("chart-09"), {
   chartType: "table",
   title: "Table"

 });
```

https://gist.github.com/mrtannerjones/ba0cbd7340f2e016fcf2 - here is a link to the above code except on github in case something isn't formatted correctly.

Sorry if this question seems terribly basic or simple, I'm still really new at learning how to code.

Answer (score 1):

Found the fix with a little help from David in the Keen.io Google group.  I actually was just missing a comma after the 'property names', but what's more interesting to me is that the data visualization works with both camel case and with underscore separators.  `property_names` and `propertyNames` both seem to work.